# Динамическое создание ImageView

Tags: android

Суть вопроса в том что есть HorizontalScrollView , в нем есть Linearlayout и в него нужно загружать картинки , желательно динамически . То есть я хочу просто добавлять ссылку на картинку в какой то из ресурсов  и чтобы динамически эта картинка добавлялась в Linearlayout , решения проблемы не прошу , хотя бы расскажите что почитать и как вообще это реализовывается

Comment: Что значит добавить ссылку в ресурс?..

Comment: ну например,  я загружаю фотки по сети с помощью picasso  , для каждой фотки мне приходиться создавать отдельное ImageView и вставлять в него эту фотку , можно ли как то сделать так чтобы я вынес все ссылки на фотки в отдельный ресурс , потом как то их считывал и передавал куда-то эти строки , а ImageView при этом создавались динамически

Comment: Всё ещё непонятна проблема, но ответ я написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут вполне себе вписываются GridView, ListView/RecycleView и их использование будет наверное более правильным чем создавать ImageView программно. Потом вдруг потребуется усложнить разметку одного изображения и код превратиться в кошмар.

Пример. Добавляете в разметку GridView с соответствующими параметрами. Пишете для него адаптер наследуемый от baseadapter в котором указываете необходимые методы. Что-нибудь вроде этого (тут используется UIL для асинхронной загрузки):

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        mData = (ArrayList<String>) items;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // Если вида нет (не создан) - разжимаем его из лайоута
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image_grid, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.thumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_thumb);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // Используем уже готовый и достаем viewHolder чтобы не 
            // делать каждый раз findViewById - это экономит до 30% процессорных циклов
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String item = (String) getItem(position);
        try {
            uri = Uri.parse(item);

            // Асинхронная загрузка изображений с помощью библиотеки UIL
            // Перед началом загрузки изображение очищается (ставим 
            // пустую серую рамку или какой-нибуть индикатор) для того чтобы 
            // в процессе загрузки не отображались предыдущие картинки
            ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(uri, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    viewHolder.thumb.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery_empty);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    viewHolder.thumb.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    Logger.Warn("Загрузка изображения не удалась (" + failReason.getType().toString() + ")");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    Logger.Warn("Загрузка изображения отменена (canceled)");
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumb;
    }
}
```

Ну и потом адаптер создается, прикручивается к списку и остается только добавлять/удалять ссылки в массив и пинать адаптер:

```
List<String> previewList = new ArrayList<>();

GridView imagesGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.images_list);
GalleryAdapter imagesAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, previewList);
imagesGrid.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);

// Где-то дальше в коде
previewList.add("http://smile.ru/ugly_smail.jpg");
imagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // команда адаптеру обновить список на экране
```

Ну а layout с записью R.layout.item_image_grid может быть просто ImageView или чем-то более сложным. В моем конкретном случае я использовал кастомный квадратный SquareFrameLayout c ImageView внутри:

```
<pkgname.SquareFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhiteBackground"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_thumb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</pkgname.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Эм. **Добавочка**. Сразу не увидел что нужна горизонтальная прокрутка. Для нее вполне подойдет [two-way-gridview](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) или начиная с API17 [HorizontalGridView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html) (до API16 для горизонтальных прокручиваемых списков использовался Gallery, который с API17 является устаревшим и не рекомендуется к использованию).

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> someIamgeUrls = ...;

for(String url : someIamgeUrls)
{
    //тут добавляйте ImageView и отображайте в них картинки
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    ...
    someContainer.addView(iv);
}
```